# Advanced Custom Fields Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So, there's a code that I've recycled multiple times on sites as it's well liked by my company. I am trying to update and recreate my portfolio due to my old hosting company wiping my entire file system. My fault for not having a back up, but lesson learned. [**Makattak.com**](http://www.makattak.com) Using [this code here,](http://pastie.org/10498095) I am unable to get anything to display.

A site I've used it on is here: [Bowhunting.com](http://www.bowhunting.com/partners/)

Here is a photo of my repeater field in ACF. I followed the same structure but still cannot get anything to display.
[image: This is my repeater field]

Can anyone offer some suggestions as far as what I am doing wrong? I've tried cutting things out, I've tried rebuilding from scratch, I just can't seem to get the loop to happen.

I am using the latest version of WordPress, and the latest purchased copy of ACF: Advanced.

Comment: When you say you can't get anything to display, do you mean the entire page is blank, or just that you're not seeing the rows? Do you have debugging turned on, and are there any error messages?

Comment: I have the else statement in there as a check, and the else displays. So my loop doesn't run at all, or it gets bypassed. EDIT* I do not get any WP errors.

Comment: Raul Cruz helped me get closer to my answer, but now I gotta figure out why I am getting everything spat out and not in the divs the need to be in.

Answer (score 1):

I know this my sounds stupid but, did you assign the template to a page and select the page on the wordpress Reading settings?

Comment: This should really be a comment to the original questions, rather than an answer.

Comment: Yes, the page is set to the correct template, also when changing the condition to just the page it still works. In my code, there is an echo statement for the else, which displays.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both Dre and Raul Cruz, I was able to find the issue.

I didn't set the Reading Settings to Home Page, static.

I revamped my code to change `the_sub_field('field');` to 
`get_sub_field('field')`

a change I made while debugging but didn't revert back

There was an issue with my syntax, and when writing the code back in, line by line, testing after each line, I was able to get what I needed back in working order

Thank you both for the help.